# Map.get() returning null although a value exists for a specific key

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying to get a value from a map.
If I iterate the Map it shows correctly all keys/values.

```
Map<String, Object> requestMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
requestMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ": Value: " + v));
```

> Key: sistemaSolarActual: Value: traders_online.SistemaSolarActual@d47f292

But if I get a specific key it returns null.

```
SistemaSolarActual sistemaActual = (SistemaSolarActual) requestMap.get("sistemaSolarActual");
```

Comment: Possible reasons: the map was modified elsewhere; typo in the key (does not look like that but some characters look alike).

Comment: @BalusC I'm not sure if the JSF-context really should be removed..

Comment: @BalusC Well, I don't get it. Javadoc says, "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key. [...]  (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)) [...] it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null" - so it could be null if the value is explicitely set to null. Doesn't seem so as you see above. Maybe you could be more specific what you mean?

Comment: @BalusC yeah, but how will this help here? "sistemaSolarActual" and "sistemaSolarActual" are identic. He's trying to get the value of the exact key how it is stored in the map.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, still don't get it. In this case the key is of type String. What are you trying to tell us?

Comment: @BalusC the above suggests to me that there's an answer to be posted here, or this question is a duplicate